# How to visualize real time 3d movement in Java?

Tags: java, 3d, visualization, wiimote

I have a code that gets data from WiiMote using GlovePie (acceleration etc). I have getters that get it to constants in real time. What would be the easiest way to visualize movement on XYZ axis using that data.

Every input is appreciated, like which library and anything other rly. I just have no idea how to start it, i am a beginner programmer, not much experience etc :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Opengl... Since you mention that you use java i suggest that you should use JOGL, a wrapper for the opengl libraries in java...

Here is a quite extensive tutorial.
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/JOGL2.0.html

As a starting demo you could possibly draw a rectangle and a cube in 3d space and move the cube using the data you extract from the wiimote

Comment: Thats actually all i want to do. Move a cube in space using data from wiimote with XYZ axis and with a scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution that only runs on windows I can recommend [Gamestudio](http://www.gamestudio.de/) as a simple 3d engine that natively supports the wiimote as input device.

I like it because it is easy and intuitive to use - if you are not familiar with 3d programming you can have a try with it.

**Disadvantage**: You have to code in C (Disadvantage only if you are not familiar with it :) )

**Advantage**: The engine has a fantastic [documentation](http://manual.3dgamestudio.net/)! A ~30 line example shows you how to rotate a 3d earth model using the wiimote.